# Could not save fileupload filename in database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, file-upload, sql-update

I can not figure out the correct code to save filename as string in the database. My code is as follows:

```
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("pimages/" + FileUpload1.FileName))
                MsgBox(FileUpload1.FileName)
            Dim newUsr As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()
            Dim newUserId As Guid = CType(newUsr.ProviderUserKey, Guid)

            ' Insert a new record into UserProfiles
            Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString
            Dim insertSql As String = "UPDATE UserProfiles Set (Pic = @Pic) Where (UserId = @UserID)"

            Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                myConnection.Open()
                Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection)

                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", newUserId)
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pic", FileUpload1.FileName)

                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                myConnection.Close()
            End Using
```

Can someone correct this please?

Comment: What errors/exceptions is it giving you?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue may be with your user id. When using dynamic SQL, both GUIDs and Strings need to be in single quotes:

```
Dim insertSql As String = "UPDATE UserProfiles Set (Pic = '@Pic') Where (UserId = '@UserID')"
```

Comment: There are other fields also in UserProfiles table but i just want to update pic field with the picture file name.

Comment: this is in a try catch block and in the catch section there is a massage box just displaying ERROR.

Comment: Updated the answer: forgot that you would need to enclose @Pic in quotes as well.